# WordPress: get_header() not including header in template file

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i  created custom post type called clients using types  plugin, and created a page for that called Clients. To fetch data from custom post types in  clients file i   created template  called clients-template.php and here is the code in that

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Client Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?> 
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content"> 
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
                            $args=array('post_type' => 'client');
                            $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
            // Start the Loop.
            while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                                    echo the_title();
                                    echo the_post_thumbnail();


            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

now when i  add page using this template i expect it to show  header and then content form this sepecific post  type but it does not add header  whats wrong pleas help me with it

Comment: Do theme contain a `header.php` file? Try to include it using `include` function.

Comment: yes there is , template is in page-templates folder and header in main folder

Comment: Then `include ('../header.php');`

Comment: Don't include the header with an include - thats not how WordPress works. get_header() should be fine to bring in the header.php template in the root of your theme. If its not working then you should enable debug define('WP_DEBUG', true); in your wp-settings.php and see if any errors come up.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Client Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
    get_header(); 
?>
<div id="main-content" class="main-content"> 
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
                            $args=array('post_type' => 'client');
                            $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
            // Start the Loop.
            while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                                    echo the_title();
                                    echo the_post_thumbnail();


            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this, and what is different? It will be more helpful to the original poster.

Comment: Please call footer so remove javascript error. because sometime javascript error so not sow header properly.