# why my functions for having a different header template aren't working?

Tags: wordpress, header-files

I wrote the function to have a different header in the home page and in the other pages, in the page.php file, but it isn't working... As I checked in Wordpress Codex it looks like I wrote the code well, so what can be the problem? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

    if (is_front_page() ) {
        get_header();

    } else {
        get_header( '404' );
    }

    ?>
```

Nor this:

```
   <?php
        get_header('404');
   ?>
```

It looks like it only recognizes the header.php file, because I tried renaming header.php as header-home.php and then using `get_header('home')` but that would not load a header...

Comment: What's the file name of your 404 header?

Comment: What's the problem? Is the normal header showing up? Or is no header showing up?

Comment: header-404.php @TamalDey

Comment: Yes the normal is showing up, but if I name the header, for example header-home.php instead of header.php and header-404.php, and then use 'home' and '404' inside get_header() it will be like there's no header. It recognizes only header.php... @rideron89

Comment: Try using `is_home()` instead of `is_front_page()`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to an issue here @rideron89

Comment: @rideron89 Tried but didn't work... It seems to me that the problem is recognizing the "header-whatever.php" file. I tried using the custom header as "header.php" and that set it up, so the problem is recognizing the "header-whatever.php" file...

Comment: I might use conditional logics to achieve my goal anyway, but I don't wanna have a single file with too many lines...

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of answers. Maybe try using `WP_DEBUG` and see if there are any answers. [Check this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233531/wordpress-get-header-not-including-header-in-template-file#comment54270855_33233531)

Comment: @rideron89 No worries, it's not very common since the syntax is fine, guess I'll use conditional logic and just get my goal done through that, if any other user will find the answer the question will be here to help the community